# Java Regex text between complex characters

Tags: java, regex, string, data-extraction

I'm trying to pull the text out of a string with the help of regex, but I haven't used it much before and I can't figure out the format for the Pattern.compile.

I want to cut out the weight (9 ounces) from the following string:

```
<li><b>Shipping Weight:</b> 9 ounces (<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/seller/shipping.html?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=0982817509&amp;seller=ATVPDKIKX0DER">View shipping rates and policies</a>)</li>
```

---

```
print("Actual Weight:" + link.outerHtml());
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Weight:\\</\\b\\>(.*?)\\ (");
Matcher m = p.matcher(link.outerHtml());
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

What should be my Pattern.compile format.  I'm trying to cut between "Weight:" and " (".

Any help would be amazing!  I've been searching for awhile now, but I couldn't find a good place to explain the formatting.

Comment: do you want to replace or match

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  Looks like I was over complicating things,  I just went with:
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Weight:</b> (.*?) \\(");

and that seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

you don't even need group. look behind works in this case:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Weight:</b> )[^(]*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be escaping the last `(`, so that'd be a problem (*I think, I don't use Java* - considering parenthesises are used in regex to express groups). I've also added `\s`'s, which mean you don't have to trim the result.

```
Pattern.compile("Weight:</b>\s+(.*?)\s+\(");
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't able to use the \s, but you were right that I wasn't escaping the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative:

```
Pattern.compile("\d*\sounces");
```

Comment: this is a risky one... who knows what text for that `<a>` link would be?

Comment: I don't think it is anymore - I edited it. This should work perfectly. Nice and easy to read. Just add "Weight" in front of your Group Match when using it in the rest of your code. No need to regex for a CONSTANT